# why Ajax Post HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-405

I'm using **Spring MVC without Spring Security**, I encounter a problem as **HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported**
I tried with

**1st Ajax Call**

```
    $('#id-posts-div').on('click', '.class-add-comment-button', function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var comment = $('#id-comment-content-textarea-'+$this.data('id') ).val().trim();
        if( comment != '' )
            $.ajax({
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/master/addComment?nsec=${nsec}&sesAccess=4",
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    postId: $this.data('id'),
                    content: comment,
                    isActive: true,
                }),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
            }).done( function ( comment ) {
                alert( JSON.stringify( comment ) );
            }).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                alert( textStatus+" : "+errorThrown );
            });
    });
```

**with following controller method.**

```
@RequestMapping( name="/addComment", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public CommentDetails addComment( @RequestBody CommentDetails commentDetails ) {
    System.out.println("MasterController.addComment()");
    System.out.println( commentDetails.toString() );
    return commentDetails;
}
```

**2nd Ajax call as**

```
    $('#id-posts-div').on('submit', 'form.class-comment-form', function ( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var formData = new FormData( this );
        var comment = $('textarea', $this).val().trim();
        alert( $this.prop("action") );
        if( comment != '' )
            $.ajax({
                url: $this.prop("action"),
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                dataType: 'json',
            }).done( function ( comment ) {
                alert( JSON.stringify( comment ) );
            }).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
                alert( textStatus+" : "+errorThrown );
            });
    });
```

**with following controller method.**

```
@RequestMapping( name="/addComment", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public CommentDetails addComment( @ModelAttribute CommentDetails commentDetails ) {
    System.out.println("MasterController.addComment()");
    System.out.println( commentDetails.toString() );
    return commentDetails;
}
```

My form is generated dynamically.
Lets say, I want to post something (using ajax), after post submitted I have generated `<HTML>` to **comment on post**. I tried it **with** `<form>` and **without** `<form>` as follows (I removed decoration `<divs>`)

```
$('#id-posts-div').prepend( '<div class="class-post-div">'+post.content
    +'<div class="class-add-cancel-comment-div-'+post.id+'"><a href="#" id="id-add-comment-a-'+post.id+'" class="class-add-cancel-comment" data-id="'+post.id+'">Add Comment</a></div>'
    +'<div class="class-add-cancel-comment-div-'+post.id+'" style="display:none;">'
//          +'<form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/master/addComment?nsec=${nsec}&sesAccess=4" class="class-comment-form" data-id="'+post.id+'">'
//          +'<input type="hidden" value="'+post.id+'" name="postId">'
    +'<textarea name="content" id="id-comment-content-textarea-'+post.id+'" class="class-textarea" '
    +'placeholder="Add comment on this post?"></textarea>'
    +'<button id="id-add-comment-button-'+post.id+'" class="class-add-comment-button class-blue-button" data-id="'+post.id+'">Add Comment</button><br><br>'
//          +'<input type="submit" id="id-submit-btn" value="Add Comment"><br><br>'
    +'<button id="id-cancel-comment-button-'+post.id+'" class="class-add-cancel-comment class-blue-button" data-id="'+post.id+'">Cancel</button>'
//          +'</form>'
    +'</div>' );
```

Comment: there's not enough info to make a clear judgment here, but it seems that you're hitting a different method. So as a hunch, try adding `/` before `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`. Check also if your class level mapping is `master`

Comment: thanks for commenting here,Class level mapping is `master`, BTW I solved my problem, I erased my `addComment` method and rewrite it, the problem was `name` attribute of `@RequestMapping`, changed it to `value` attribute, now it is working...